# get key corresponding to value in js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an object such as :

```
var inspectionMapping = {'a_pillar_lh' : "A Pillar LH",
                       'b_pillar_lh'  : "B Pillar LH"};

console.log(inspectionMapping['a_pillar_lh']);
// Which gives me correct "A Pillar LH".
```

I am able to get the value corresponding to key.

But I am not able to get the key corresponding to value in javascript  Object.

Such as I have `"A Pillar LH"` and I need to get the corresponding key     which is `a_pillar_lh`.

I have tried to use `indexOf` but no success.

Comment: Something like `Object.keys(obj)`

Comment: You have to loop through the keys, checking if the value matches your search.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/n0y75guq/

Comment: @RayonDabre : Jsfiddle example works for me. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply fetch all the keys using `Object.keys()` and then use `.find()` function to get the key out from that array, and then nicely wrap it in a function to make it modular.

```js
var inspectionMapping = {
  'a_pillar_lh': "A Pillar LH",
  'b_pillar_lh': "B Pillar LH"
};

Object.prototype.getKey = function(value) {
  var object = this;
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
};


alert(inspectionMapping.getKey("A Pillar LH"));
```

**EDIT** For those who don't want to use ES6

```
Object.prototype.getKey = function(value) {
      var object = this;
      for(var key in object){
         if(object[key]==value) return key;
      }
};
```

Comment: Its returning me the below errror. return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
                                           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL Does your environment supports ES 6?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : have tried but it is giving me error   "has no method 'find'"

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL `find()` is also a new installment to ES6. Better see the solution give below by me. `Object.keys` was introduced with ES5. So i guess that wont cause problems in your environment.

Comment: @void  using `for..in` is dangerous at times. It will iterate over the enumerable properties until the end of the proto chain. Better to include `hasOwnProperty` check while using `for..in` over objects.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : ok trying one more time :)

Comment: @void Who said `find` is a jquery's method. Yes indeed jquery has a method called `find`. But what you have used here is a function belongs to ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : updated one is working now :) Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL You should say thanks to void. cuz you used his answer. :)

Comment: @void :  yeahh :) Thanks buddy :) I have already upvoted the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
Object.keys(inspectionMapping).find(key => inspectionMapping[key] === 'A Pillar LH');
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a Lodash solution to this, here's one I commonly use. This method inverts the object, swapping keys for values, and then finds the key by looking up the value against this new object.

```js
var inspectionMapping = {
 'a_pillar_lh': "A Pillar LH",
 'b_pillar_lh': "B Pillar LH"
};

var getKey = function( obj, value ) {
 var inverse = _.invert( obj );
 return _.get( inverse, value, false );
};

alert( 'The key for "A Pillar LH" is "' + getKey( inspectionMapping, 'A Pillar LH' ) + '"' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```